# How to get rid of nearly zero numbers in expressions

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, simplex

I tried to do a simplex algorithm in Python and all the tableaus and values were right but, at the last iteration, there were values on the objective function that were off
I'm using `sympy` and `numpy`.
All of the values but 2 are correct and I don't know where did they come from. I even tested the multiplication line and made the add myself, it was supposed to work, but the 5th and 7th numbers are weird.

The results of the old line, the line that should be added to the old line and the actual result:

[image: the results of the old line, the line that should be added to the old line and the actual result]

I'm using `sympy` to use a symbolic value for M. The old line should be added to the "to be added line" and the result should be like `[0, 0, 0, 1*M + 1.4, 0.5, 1*M + 0.5, 5.4]` but the 5th and 7th elements are weird values that shouldn't be on the line and I don't know how to fix it
The `M` on the last term of the array should be `0`.

```py
for index, row in enumerate(self.tableau):
         if pivot_row != index:
            multiplier = -row[entering_column]
            print(f"Index {index}, Multiplcador {multiplier}")
            new_tableau[index] = multiplier * new_tableau[pivot_row] + self.tableau[index]
```

This is the part of the code that makes the changes above

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces your error and that people can run directly.

Comment: Sympy and numpy aren't meant to be mixed together. Try to use either one or the other.  Also note that sympy works quite unintuively when you use floats, you might want to use sympy fractions instead.  Without reproducible test data, it is hard to guess what's going on.

Comment: Note that the development version of SymPy has a simplex method.

Answer (score 1):

The values you are seeing are very small numbers instead of 0 (note the `e-16`). Since those are SymPy expressions, if you add the line

```py
new_tableau[index] = [i.n(chop=True) for i in new_tableau[index]]
```

that should eliminate those "nearly 0" values.